# Neo4j - extract all subgraphs from neo4j database

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a similar question to the one asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43337932/how-to-extract-all-subgraph-from-neo4j), however, the solution proposed didn't work for me.

My Neo4j database has a lot of sub-graphs, each one of them contains varying number of nodes.

I would like to extract some kind of a list which will contain all sub-graphs separated.

[image]

In the example given, I would like to get 3 groups, where each group contains all the nodes in the sub-graph which the group represents.

How can I get all groups of nodes by Cypher query?

All the solutions that I have found for this problem require "root" node which I don't have in this case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [graph algorithms](https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neo4j-graph-algorithms) plugin and specifically [connected components algorithm](https://neo4j.com/docs/graph-algorithms/current/algorithms/connected-components/) to label all the isolated subgraphs in your graph and then export them and group them later when exported by set id.

**Example:**

[image]

create a sample graph

```
MERGE (nAlice:User {id:'Alice'})
MERGE (nBridget:User {id:'Bridget'})
MERGE (nCharles:User {id:'Charles'})
MERGE (nDoug:User {id:'Doug'})
MERGE (nMark:User {id:'Mark'})
MERGE (nMichael:User {id:'Michael'})

MERGE (nAlice)-[:FRIEND]->(nBridget)
MERGE (nAlice)-[:FRIEND]->(nCharles)
MERGE (nMark)-[:FRIEND]->(nDoug)
MERGE (nMark)-[:FRIEND]->(nMichael);
```

Run connected components (unionFind) algorithm and return nodes in the same subgraph:

```
CALL algo.unionFind.stream('User', 'FRIEND', {})
YIELD nodeId,setId
RETURN setId,collect(algo.getNodeById(nodeId)) AS nodes_from_specific_subgraph
```

This will return:

```
╒═══════╤══════════════════════════════════════════════════╕
│"setId"│"specific_subgraph"                               │
╞═══════╪══════════════════════════════════════════════════╡
│4      │[{"id":"Doug"},{"id":"Mark"},{"id":"Michael"}]    │
├───────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│0      │[{"id":"Alice"},{"id":"Bridget"},{"id":"Charles"}]│
└───────┴──────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
```

Comment: added an example

Comment: Thank you! I wasn't familiar with the graph lgorithm plugin. I have followed your example and that worked for me!