# Checking if Neo4j graph is coherent

Tags: graph, neo4j, cql

I want to check if all my nodes in Neo4j database are coherently connected.
This means there should be only one graph, in which all nodes are. So there should be no seperate graphs.
How could I check this? I already searched in forum, but sadly didnt find a suitable answer for me. Also it should be a scalable and performant solution.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Neo4j - extract all subgraphs from neo4j database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53447957/neo4j-extract-all-subgraphs-from-neo4j-database)

Comment: I know the OP probably does not know that separate graphs are know as [partitions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_partition), but once that is known, as I just noted, it should be obvious that the question is a duplicate. So if there is only one sub-graph then it would be coherent.

Comment: THanks for the answer. I whink I can derive my solution from this. But could you tell me how to include that algo.unionFind procedure into neo4j? Because it doesnt seem to know this procedure on my system

Comment: See: The Neo4j Graph Algorithms User Guide v3.4 [1.2. Installation](https://neo4j.com/docs/graph-algorithms/current/introduction/#_installation)